# Install nextcloud on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, nextcloud

Can I install nextcloud on Raspbian? (I have a RPI3)

I know that a image of it already exists, but I would want to know if something installed from tarball. If so, what web server would be better (apache, lighttpd, nginx)

This is my lsb information:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie

lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  1,8T  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0  1,8T  0 part /tmp/extusb
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14,8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0    1K  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p7 179:7    0 13,5G  0 part /
├─mmcblk0p5 179:5    0   32M  0 part /media/pi/SETTINGS
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  1,2G  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p6 179:6    0   66M  0 part /boot
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59873/discussion-on-question-by-sebelk-install-nextcloud-on-raspbian).

Answer (score 5):

There is a tarball: https://nextcloud.com/install/#instructions-server

Since it looks to be written in PHP, it doesn't need to be built and you don't need a special ARM version for that Pi.

I'm guessing it plays nicest with apache.  In any case, [Nextcloud has documentation for the server](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/).  Raspbian is a form of GNU/Linux, so you will want things that apply to "linux" (since it apparently won't work on Windows, the docs are probably very linux oriented).  If there are further distinctions made, you want the instructions for *Debian* (preferrably) or *Ubuntu*.

If you run into a snag there and need to ask for clarification, they also have [a forum](https://help.nextcloud.com/).  You might also try our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Since the userbase here is smaller, and not necessarily all nextcloud users, avoid asking detailed questions about Nextcloud here unless you believe they are *specific to* the Pi or Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub tere is a install script (Shell) for NextCloud on Raspberry Pi:

- [nextcloud/nextcloudpi:  Build code for NextcloudPi: Raspberry Pi, Odroid, Rock64, Docker, curl installer...](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloudpi)

> NextCloudPi
>
> This is the build code for NextCloudPi.
>
> NextCloudPi is a ready to use image for Raspberry Pi.
>
> This code also generates the NextCloudPi ARM docker image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distribution called **NextCloudPi** to directly install operating system with preconfigured *NextCloud* on all *Raspberry Pi* models. See [the install instructions](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/how-to-install-nextcloudpi/126308) for more details.